# Delete directories in folder is not working after folder is updated

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm having an automated test that is deleting all the projects inside Projects folder.

```
folder = myPath\Projects\Project1
                         Project2
                           ...
```

The test executes like this:

```
deleteProjectsFromFolder,createNewProject,deleteProjectsFromFolder
```

The code for deleteProjectsFromFolder is this:

```
        for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
            try:
                if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                    os.unlink(file_path)
                elif os.path.isdir(file_path): shutil.rmtree(file_path)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

First delete projects from folder works but the second one after new project is created does not delete the directories(projects) anymore. What should I do in this case?Are there some other solutions for this?

I have tried with different approaches to remove the directories but it nevers works on the second deleteProjectsFromFolder.

Comment: I'm guessing your code is attempting to remove files which have already been removed by `rmtree`. You should either skip files which are in directories you are going to remove anyway, or remove directories only after removing files.

Comment: The blanket `except` handler is a bug, you really should not put in `except` clauses until you understand what your code is doing.

Comment: @tripleee I have used other approaches to delete the directories but the same behaviour...only the first time the folders are deleted. The second deleteProjectsFromFolder is never working.

Comment: Can you update the question with a [mcve]?